# Printing one variable prints the value of the other variable (in C++)

Tags: c++

I recently started learning C++. Today i wanted to make a demo "Player" class which has x and y positions.

I'm not sure if my method is correct or not but what I'm worried about is when i print (x , y) int the end it gets printed as (y,x).

Player.h :

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// CLASS -----------------------------------------------------------------

class Player {

private :

std::string name;
float x, y;
const int SPEED = 5;


public:

Player() : x(0) , y(0) {

}

float* getX() {
    return &x;
}

float* getY() {
    return &y;
}

std::string getName() {
    return name;
}

void setX(float block) {
    x = block;
}

void setY(float block) {
    y = block;
}

void move( float* axis , int direction) {
    *axis += direction * SPEED;
}

void setName(std::string block) {
    name = block;
}



};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

std::string getInput(std::string value) {
std::string temp;
std::cout << "Enter "<< value <<" : ";
std::cin >> temp;
std::cout << std::endl;
return temp;
}
```

Player.cpp :

```
#include "Player.h"

int main() {

Player p1;
std::string axis;
int dir;

float* yAxis = p1.getY();
float* xAxis = p1.getX();

p1.setName(getInput("name"));

std::cout << "Your name is " << p1.getName() << std::endl;

std::cout << "Enter 'y' to move in y axis , 'x' to move in x axis : ";
std::cin >> axis;

std::cout << "Enter a positive / negative value for the direction";
std::cin >> dir;

if (axis.compare("y")) {
    if (dir < 0) {
        p1.move(yAxis, -1);
    }
    else {
        p1.move(yAxis, 1);
    }
}
else if (axis.compare("x")) {
    if (dir < 0) {
        p1.move(xAxis, -1);
    }
    else {
        p1.move(xAxis, 1);
    }
}

std::cout << "Position ( " << *xAxis << " , " << *yAxis << " )" << std::endl;

getInput("anything to exit");
}
```

Can someone answer where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Consider reading the documentation for [`std::string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare). It does not return what you expect it to return. `axis == "y"` is you want instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string::compare` returns 0 if the strings are equal!

This is the opposite way to how you are expecting.

Replacing with `axis == "y"` &c. would be more readable, although there are better ways of achieving this from a performance perspective.

Comment: Oh! 
Thank you !